# capturar valor selected de datatables (Jquery) y guardar en array

Tags: select, datatable

Estoy usando datatable de Jquery, me gustaría que al ir seleccionando valores de la  tabla, estos se guarden en un array.
He intentado lo siguiente.

```
$('#tblMsnToColab tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } );


     $('#tblMsnToColab tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        i=0;
         idMen = tblColab.row( this ).data();
         colabArray = [];
        colabArray[i]=idMen['id'];
        i++;
    });
```

Mi problema es que al hacer click en el tr, a la variable i siempre le asigno el 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función each de jQuery la cual permite pasarle un contador como parámetro de entrada:

```
    $("#tblMsnToColab>tbody>tr").each(function(i) {
       $(this).on('click', function() {
          $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
          array.push(i); // guardo el contador, pero puedes guardar un atributo 'data' o lo que quieras
          alert(array);
       });                  
    });
```

Te dejo un ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/694818/

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias, en mi caso el color no me es necesario, ya que de eso se encarga el css de datatables, No conocia el array.push

Comment: El color lo he puesto simplemente para resaltar el click, la idea es usar el contador como parámetro de la función each para así poderlo incrementar y que no se te quede a 0. En cuanto a la función push se usa para añadir objetos al array directamente sin tener que tener en cuenta la posición mediante un for.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que me ha dado resultado es lo siguiente.

```
 var colabArray = [];
    var i=0;

 $('#tblMsnToColab tbody').off( 'click', 'tr');
$('#tblMsnToColab tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) { //Si estoy deseleccionando
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        idColab = tblColab.row( this ).data(); //Tomo el id
        $.each(colabArray,  function( key,idColabAr ) {
            if(colabArray[key]==idColab['id']){ //Busco y comparado id el array
                colabArray.splice(key, 1); //Elimino desde la posicion empezando por 0,un elemento
                i=i-1; //Tengo que restar uno a la i, ya que elimino un elemento.
            }
        });

    }

    else{ //Estoy marcando
        idColab = tblColab.row( this ).data();
        colabArray[i]=idColab['id'];
        i++;
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    }

    console.log(colabArray.join(';'))//Esto es para separar los elementos por ;

    $("#creaMensaje").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
        colabArray.length=0; //Borro el array al salir
        i=0;
    });
});
```

La idea es en una datatable, hace multi selección, cuando hago click y selecciono una fila, voy guardando el valor en un array, cuando hago click sobre una fila seleccionada, deselecciono la fila, busco ese elemento en el array recorriendo este y  elimino el elemento del array.

Estoy seguro de que se puede hacer de alguna otra forma mas eficiente, agradezco alguna mejora. Gracias